# Is there a way to capture spreadsheet title changes in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to capture events (like triggers) on spreadsheet title changes in Google Script. I have read through Triggers (onEdit) in Google Scripts but it only captures Cell Edits. I am trying to change cell values based on the Document Titles.

I have tried using my own function

```
function (){
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  return name
}
```

This works fine however the script only runs once when the document is open. I need to make the script run on every document title change.

Thanks

Comment: Try the change trigger (it's one of the installable triggers for spreadsheets).

Comment: Consider subscribing to the document with the Drive REST API